# AngularFirebase 2 check if user exists then add to database

Tags: javascript, angular, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I want to add a new user to firebase realtime Database, i have managed to query the databse to find if the email input already exists

```js
onSubmit(form: NgForm){

    var user = this._visitorService.getIndividualVisitor(form.value.email);

    user.valueChanges().subscribe(list=>{
      console.log(list);
      if(list.length ===0 ){
        console.log('email doesnt exist, creating new user');
        this._visitorService.addVisitor(form.value)  
      } else{
        console.log('email existst');
        this._visitorService.updateVisitor(form.value)
      }
    })
}
  
getIndividualVisitor(email:string){
    this.list = this.firebase.list('visitors', ref => ref.orderByChild('email').equalTo(email));
    return this.list;
}
```

The problem i have is that the `user.valueChanges()` is called every time the database is updated 
this means that every time I add a new user the update user function is also called, what would be the correct way to do this.
I am using     `"angularfire2": "^5.0.0-rc.4",` and `"firebase": "4.8.0",`

Comment: Request your database only when the user validates his form. One request, up-to-date with the database.

Answer (score 1):

I think using Firebase Auth together with Cloud Functions would solve your issue.

Use  [Firebase Authentication](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/) to create a user.

Then deploy a Cloud Function which listens on the user OnCreate event.

```
exports.newUser = functions.auth.user().onCreate(event => {
  // Add something to your database here.
});
```

Documentation for Cloud Function Triggers can be found here: [Firebase Authentication Triggers](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/auth-events)

Comment: does this work with firebase realtime Database because im not using cloud firestore

Comment: Yes. With my approach you're letting Firebase handling everything regarding user creation / authentication. By deploying a cloud function you can listen for every time a new user is created. And inside that function you can access your database, storage, or something else you need.

Comment: are there any video tutorials of using this method?

Comment: I'm not sure regarding video but the documentation by Firebase is amazing, here is a link to using Firebase Auth Getting Started: https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/start and here is a link to getting started with Cloud Functions: https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/get-started